# DynamicActivity - How to invoke a workflow that stored in Database?

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2010, workflow-foundation-4

This is proof of concept project - The goal is to create an application that receive some system wide events and based on some business rules invokes a specific workflow.

The workflows are created separately and the xaml source is stored in a database.

Following is the code that used to invoke the workflow:

```
public void RaiseEvent(IEvent e, IEventData eventData)
{ 

    var typeName = e.GetType().FullName;

    // Query Db for all workflows for the event
    var repo = new WorkflowRepository();

    var workflows = repo.GetActiveWorkflowsByEvent(typeName);

    foreach (var wf in workflows)
    {

        var condition =   
 ConditionEvaluator.PrepareCondition(wf.Condition.Expression, eventData);

        var okToStart = ConditionEvaluator.Evaluate(condition);
        if (okToStart)
        {

           // Next line is throwing an exeption
            object o = XamlServices.Parse(wf.WorkflowDefinition.Expression);


            DynamicActivity da = o as DynamicActivity;

            WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(da,  
                   new Dictionary<string, object>   
                       {{ "EventData", eventData }});                   


        }

    }
```

We have created very simple workflow that runs without problems on its own. But when xaml is being loaded using XamlService.Parse it throw following exception:

```
System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException was unhandled
  Message='No matching constructor found on type 'System.Activities.Activity'.   
You can use the Arguments or FactoryMethod directives to construct this type.' 
Line number '1' and line position '30'.
```

Any idea what is wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what is causing your problem, I have used XamlServices.Load() in the past without any problems, but the easiest way of loading a workflow XAML at runtime is by using the ActivityXamlServices.Load(). See [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2010/03/07/loading-xaml-workflows-in-wf4.aspx) for an example.

Comment: Thanks, That exactly what I did.
I have posted the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have solved this by using ActivityXamlServices

So Instead of this line:

```
object o = XamlServices.Parse(wf.WorkflowDefinition.Expression);
```

I am using following snippet:

```
var mStream = new memoryStream(
    ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(wf.WorkflowDefinition.Expression));

object o = ActivityXamlServices.Load(mStream);
```